# AngularFire - combine two FireStore collections with the same pushId items

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on some project with AngularFire + FireStore.

My Firestore model looks like this:

- Collection 1

  - key1 {some data}
  - key2 {some data}
- Collection 2

  - key1 {other data}
  - key2 {other data}

Now I need to show list where I have some data from the first collection, and some data from another one. How to create such a list?

It seems to be pointless to make two observables and then merge it.

```js
const collection = this.afStore.collection<any>(collectionName);
    return collection.snapshotChanges()
      .map(participants => {
        return participants.map(participant => {
          const data = participant.payload.doc.data();
          const id = participant.payload.doc.id;
          return {id, ...data};
        });
      });
```

I have this code that takes data + id, and now I need to use this id to pull data from another collection, but don't know how.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I did mine...

The "projects" data has customer_doc_id, customer_builder_doc_id, customer_contractor_doc_id, which are doc_id of other data collections in Firestore.  The command mergeMap works in rxjs^5.5.0.

```
 private getProjectsCombineObservables(): Observable<any[]> {
this.projectsCollection = this.afs.collection<Project>('projects', ref =>
  ref.orderBy('job_number', 'desc'));
return this.projectsCollection.snapshotChanges()
  .map(actions => {
    return actions.map(a => {
      const project_data = a.payload.doc.data() as Project;
      const doc_id = a.payload.doc.id;

      let observable1 = this.getCustomer(project_data.customer_doc_id);
      let observable2 = this.getBuilder(project_data.customer_builder_doc_id);
      let observable3 = this.getContractor(project_data.customer_contractor_doc_id);

      const combinedData = Observable.combineLatest(observable1, observable2, observable3, (data1, data2, data3) => {
        return { ...data1, ...data2, ...data3 };
      });

      return combinedData.map(data => Object.assign({}, { doc_id, ...project_data, ...data }));
    });
  }).mergeMap(observables => Observable.combineLatest(observables));
```

}

Comment: sorry, but you can't just throw methods around without explaining where they came from. What is this.getCustomer()? What is this.getBuilder()? Where did they come from? What are they doing?

Answer (score 1):

Wohoo! I did it :)

So it should be like this:

```js
const collection = this.afStore.collection<any>('collection1');
    return collection.snapshotChanges()
      .map(participants => {
        return participants.map(participant => {
          const data = participant.payload.doc.data();
          const id = participant.payload.doc.id;
          return this.afStore.doc('collection2/' + id).valueChanges()
            .map(data2 => Object.assign({}, {id, ...data, ...data2}));
        });
      }).flatMap(observables => Observable.combineLatest(observables));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const collection = this.afStore.collection<any>('collection1');
    return collection.snapshotChanges()
      .map(participants => {
        return participants.map(participant => {
          const data = participant.payload.doc.data();
          const id = participant.payload.doc.id;
          return this.afStore.doc('collection2/' + id).valueChanges()
            .map(data2 => Object.assign({}, {id, ...data, ...data2}));
        });
      }).flatMap(observables => Observable.combineLatest(observables));
```

Comment: I tried this code but is return a observable of observable. how can I get the data. When I do a subscribe it return a array of observable.

Comment: you should not post your issue as an answer. Instead comment to the respected answer.

Answer (score 1):

**After trying multiple solution I get it done with RXJS combineLatest, take operator. Using map function we can combine result.**

```
combineLatest(
    this.fireBaseService.getFromCollection1(),
    this.fireBaseService.getFromCollection2(),
    //In collection 2 we have document with reference id of collection 1
)
.pipe(
    take(1),
).subscribe(
    ([dataFromCollection1, dataFromCollection2]) => {

        this.dataofCollection1 = dataFromCollection1.map((data) => {
            return {
                id: data.payload.doc.id,
                ...data.payload.doc.data() as {},
            }
            as IdataFromCollection1;
        });

        this.dataofCollection2 = dataFromCollection2.map((data2) => {
            return {
                id: data2.payload.doc.id,
                ...data2.payload.doc.data() as {},
            }
            as IdataFromCollection2;
        });

        console.log(this.dataofCollection2, 'all feeess');

        const mergeDataFromCollection =
            this.dataofCollection1.map(itm => ({
                payment: [this.dataofCollection2.find((item) => (item.RefId === itm.id))],
                ...itm
            }))

        console.log(mergeDataFromCollection, 'all data');
    },
```